# Find the minimum and maximum distances from point $(2,6)$ to ellipse $9x^2+8y^2-36x-16y-28=0$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, simple-functions

Having trouble with this. I'm not getting any ideas.

> Find the minimum and maximum distances of point $(2,6)$ from the ellipse $$9x^2+8y^2-36x-16y-28=0$$

Comment: Do you know calculus ?  vector calculus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Your ellipse has the equation

$$9(x-2)^2+8(y-1)^2=72$$
or

$$(\frac {x-2}{\sqrt {8}})^2+(\frac {y-1}{3})^2=1$$

it can be paremetrized by

$$x=\sqrt {8}\cos (t)+2$$
$$y=3\sin (t)+1$$

the square of the distance from the point $(2,6) $ to a point of the ellipse is

$$D^2(t)=8\cos^2 (t)+9\sin^2 (t)-30\sin (t)+25$$
$$=\sin^2 (t)-30\sin (t)+33$$
$$=(\sin (t)-1)(\sin (t)+1-30)+4\ge 4$$

Your distance is $D(\frac {\pi}{2})=2$ .

Comment: Can I solve it without  using differention

Comment: @user452206 Is it okay now without diff.

Comment: ellipse centred on $(2,1)$ major axis parallel to $y$ ( pointing towards $(2,6)$).
Closest point is $(2,4)$ most distant point is $(2,-2)$